# VK_DOWN & VK_UP not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, paintcomponent

I am trying to make a JAVA program that when you open it, a circle pops up and you can move it. Heres my code so far.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.security.Key;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class WalkerCC extends JPanel implements ActionListener,     KeyListener{

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
double x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

public WalkerCC() {
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 7, 40, 40));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    x += velx;
    y += vely;
}

public void up() {
    vely = -1.5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void down() {
    vely = 1.5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void left() {
    velx = -1.5;
    vely = 0;

}

public void right() {
        velx = 1.5;
        vely = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up();
    }

    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down();
    }

    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right();
    }

    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left();
    }

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

The problem is, if I open the application and click the left arrow, it goes left, and same for right. But once I do the up and down it stops moving and doesent work!

Comment: Shouldn't `g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 7, 40, 40));` be `g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));`? Btw, it would be better to use Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener

Answer (score 4):

```
g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 7, 40, 40));
```

Should be:

```
g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
```